# ubuntu 13.04 python2.7 cannot import matplotlib and other module

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter

I have just installed matplotlib to generate some plots. but this module cannot be imported in python interpreter. although it can be imported in ipython, when i use ipython to execute those examples. it didn't show anything...

besides that, i also can't use idle.

```
 IDLE can't import Tkinter.  Your Python may not be configured for Tk.
```

my os is ubuntu 13.04 and the default python version is 3.0. But i install python 2.7 manually.

is there anything wrong with my python configuration.

my python path is

```
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

i just find that only when i start python in terminal, those module cannot be imported!

the sys.path in ipython is

```
['',
 '/usr/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

but after i add those path to PYTHONPATH, it still cannot work.

```
ImportError: numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsUnicodeEscapeString
```

so how can i overwrite the pythonpath??

Comment: FYI the default Python package in Ubuntu 13.04 is still 2.7.4 (try `$ python --version`). How exactly did you install matplotlib and numpy?

Comment: just used apt-get install...

Comment: I reinstalled ubuntu 12.04 yesterday...

Comment: Did you `apt-get` the `python-` or the `python3-` versions of these packages?